# Getting UnsupportedClassVersionError in Eclipse JPA project which does not make sense

Tags: java, eclipse, jpa, java-7, java-6

I have a weird situation here. I am getting an error about Java 1.7 when I am using Java 1.6 everywhere.

I am using **Eclipse Kepler 32-bit**. 
The JPA implementation I am using is **EclipseLink 2.6.0**.

In Window --> Preferences --> Java --> Installed JREs, I have jdk1.6.0_34 (default) checked and its location is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_34`. This is the print screen:

[image: Eclipse Preferences Installed JREs Window]

I create a new JPA Project. In *Target runtime* I selected jdk1.6.0_34. This is the print screen:

[image: Eclipse New JPA Project Window]

I click on Modify... button in Configuration section to confirm I am working on Java 1.6. This is the print screen:

[image: Eclipse Project Facets Window]

I then created a simple class to test JPA:

```
package com.test;

import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

public class TestJPA {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("MyTestJpaProject");
        emf.close();
    }
}
```

When I run it I got an error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/eclipse/persistence/jpa/PersistenceProvider : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProviderResolverHolder$DefaultPersistenceProviderResolver.getPersistenceProviders(PersistenceProviderResolverHolder.java:117)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:76)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
    at com.test.TestJPA.main(TestJPA.java:16)
```

This is strange. I am using Java 1.6 everywhere yet Eclipse is giving me this error message about Java 1.7. What could be the reason?

Comment: @KrutikJayswal no I am not using ant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means that some plugin you are using was built using java 1.7 and it would require 1.7 or greater jre. Check the plugin which contains the class mentioned in the stack trace.

Comment: I am only using **EclipseLink 2.6.0**. The error is happening by this code: `Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("MyTestJpaProject");`. Does this mean **EclipseLink 2.6.0** can only work with Java 1.7 and above?

Comment: just checked the doc: **The minimum requirement to run EclipseLink 2.6.0 is Java 7. Please ensure that you have Java 7 installed and it's working.** Thanks. Btw, is there any JPA 2.1 implementation which can work with Java 1.6?

Comment: @ChumboChappati DataNucleus v3.3 does support JDK1.6. v4+ of DataNucleus requires JDK1.7+

Comment: @NeilStockton Thanks. Will check it out one day. For now I am concentrating on EclipseLink. I moved to EclipseLink 2.5.2